# Delete in PhotoKit: can you skip "Recently Deleted"?

Tags: ios, ios8, photokit, photosframework

As of iOS8, when you delete a photo, it goes into a trashcan-analog called "Recently Deleted". This happens when you delete via Photos.app, or via the PhotoKit API (using `PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets()`).

In Photos.app, you can then go into "Recently Deleted", and *really* delete that photo. Is there a way to do that in PhotoKit?

Comment: I don't think so. Depending on why you're looking for insta-delete, though, there might be good ways to get a temporary asset to work with...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. The only deletion API is `deleteAssets`.